# Regular expressions: Multiline-issue with html

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm playing around with websites and regular expressions in C#. I have this situation:

```
             <a href="path/to/image">
    <img src="thumbnail"></a>
```

That outlining is how my application gets the content of a given web site. Tabs and breaklines not the same for each row.

I use gskinner to check the regex (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) and I have created this regular expression:

```
            (?i)<a([^>]+)>\W.*</a>
```

Flags: Multiline

Gskinner shows that the pattern is correct. But when I put in c# (regEx.Matches(...)) it can not find the matches anymore.

Does anyone have any clue how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Don't to it with Regex. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/590747/390819. One of the right tools for parsing HTML is http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and your sample string

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

-

```
var href = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("a")
    .Select(n => n.Attributes["href"].Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();

var src = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("img")
    .Select(n => n.Attributes["src"].Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Okay, cool. I tried the HtmlAgilityPack, but when I replace FirstOrDefault() with ToList() I get an object reference not set exception. I want all links in the page, not one. How to do this?

Comment: You can add a `.Where(n => n.Attributes["someattr"]!=null)` before `Select` to make sure attribute is not null